# "It may be inaccessible due to protection level"

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add collision with some picture boxes and the error explaining that this is inaccessible shows up. I am quite garbage at code and it may be obvious to some but not to me.

Here be my code

```
Public Sub Panel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Paint
    If Panel1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(P1Character.Bounds) Then
        collision = True
    Else : collision = False
    End If
End Sub
```

The two collision's is the part being said that it is inaccessible due to protection level.

Comment: What is `collision` supposed to be? Where do you think that it is declared such that it should be accessible?